# How to define or set multiple hash values to zero for each undefined hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

In the code below there are multiple occupations whose value is zero but are not defined in the hash. Example: Plumber is not defined in `%data` but I need to set `$data{'Plumber'}` to zero. There may be more than one occupation with no values. I did this with with an if-else, but is there a better way?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
%data = ('Teacher' => 45, 'Doctor' => 40,'Driver' => '10');
if (exists($data{'Plumber'})) {
   print "Number of doctor is $data{'Plumber'}\n";
}
else {
    $data{'Plumber'} = 0;
    print "Number of doctor is $data{'Plumber'}\n";
}
print Dumper \%data;
```

Is there any way to set all the undefined values of `%data` to zero?

The condition is - first check what values in the hash are undefined and set zero to those respective keys not all.

Please see my actual piece of code below: [question edited on 30th March'17]

```
 my %map = (
 blk     => 'Block',
 hrd     => 'Hard',
 sft     => 'Soft',
 success => 'Success',
 unk     => 'Unknown',
 );
 my %report;
 for ( `$stats` ) {
 my ($val, $type) = split;
 $report{$map{$type}} = $val;
 }
 \%report;
 $_ //= 0 for values %report;
 print Dumper \%report;
```

I am not able to set 0 for all unassigned value within hash %report, 
per below comment, I used `$_ //= 0 for values %report;` to achieve this but here I got confused when I am mapping two hashes as I am a very beginner in Perl
FYI.. `$stats` is a query which I am using to fetch some values from the logs and below the sample output.

```
 10 blk
 20 sft
 50 success
```

any idea how to do with this would be highly appreciated

Comment: If you have an array of all the keys, you could just iterate through it and set undefined values to zero in `%data`

Comment: my  %data hash's result is dynamic that means some of the keys values may remain undefined sometimes but again sometimes they may have some integer values. (I am storing all the hash values from a query that may return only one value so my %data will have only one key value pair but I want to print all the values of hash but undefined should remain 0)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a default:

```
print "Plumber number: ", ($data{'Plumber'} || 0), "\n";
```

This will use 0 instead of any of Perl's non-true values, e.g., `""`, `0`, `undef`. If you have such values and do not want to use 0 instead, use the `//` operator instead of `'||`.

Comment: Note that `""` is also false, so if `$data{'Plumber'}` is `""` this will change that to 0. Instead, use the defined-or `//` operator which is like `||` but checks if they're defined.

Comment: @Schwern Right, thanks. From the original question I was assuming it's either numbers or undefined.

Comment: @Robert: Even with numbers, it would still alter `000` or `0E0` to `0`. It's best to use defined-or if that's what you mean.

Comment: my  %data hash's result is dynamic that means some of the keys values may remain undefined sometimes but again sometimes they may have some integer values. (I am storing all the hash values from a query that may return only one value so my %data will have only one key value pair but I want to print all the values of hash but undefined should remain 0)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably used to something like Ruby's `Hash.new(0)`. Perl has several libraries to implement this, [Hash::DefaultValue](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::DefaultValue) is from a good author. Trouble is they rely on tying, Perl's odd way of letting an object act like a data type, which is slow and has caveats.

Instead, there's several techniques. Simplest is to apply the default yourself, as in [@Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43009502/14660), but use the defined-or `//` operator instead of the logical-or `||` operator.

```
my $value = $data{'Plumber'} // 0;
```

The difference is subtle, but it protects you from a false value like `""` from being turned into a 0. Instead, the 0 default will only be used if `$data{'Plumber'}` contains the undefined value or does not exist.

---

Second, if the set of keys is fixed, you can explicitly set all the values to 0. Again, using the defined-or `//=` version of `||=`.

```
for my $key (@keys) {
    $data{$key} //= 0;
}
```

---

There's a few options for encapsulating this default. Simplest is to wrap up your hash in a little class to do this for you.

```
package MyStuff;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = shift;

    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub get {
    my $self = shift;
    my $key = shift;

    return $self->{$key} // 0;
}
```

Then...

```
my $stuff = MyStuff->new(\%data);
my $val = $stuff->get("Plumber");
```

There will be the extra overhead of the method call, and users have to adapt to the object interface, but it's faster than tying.

Comment: thank you..! can you see my edited question and advise, please. anyway, I can't ask a new question at least for 6 months :)

Comment: @PankajKumar Instead of doing `$_ //= 0 for values %report;` do `$report{$_} //= 0 for values %map`. That will go through all the values in `%map` like `Block`, and `Hard` and make sure they default to 0 in the `%report`.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case allows to just preset all values of the hash with `0`. Add this after `my %report;`:

```
@report{values %map} = (0) x keys %map;
```

Why this works:

`@report{...}` sets multiple values of your hash. The values of `%map` are used as keys for `%report`. `(0) x ...` produces a list of zeros. Since the `x` operator expects a scalar on its right side, `keys %map` is executed in scalar context and produces the number 5. Therefore `%report` is filled with its default values and later only the values present in your `$stats` are overwritten.